# Informatica Mapping: Joiner must have exactly two inputs

Tags: mapping, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I get the following message when I try to validate the mapping (see Warning attached):

...Joiner jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason must have exactly two inputs.

WARNING: Joiner transformation jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason Condition field OR_CASE_ID1 is unconnected.

I have a joiner (jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason) and expression (exp_Text) that I would like to  join.  I tried to do this with a normal joiner (jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason).  However, the data from the jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason does not connect to this jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason.  See Joiners-Two Inputs attached.

Should I be using a different transformation to join the joiner and expression?

I tried to use Sorting but I still get the same error message.  Am I using the Sorting correctly? Please see the attached images.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5fK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziEZV.png)

Comment: Could you add a snapshot of the transformations before jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason ? That would help to understand what is connected and in what order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join flows that originate from the same source (let's call that a self-join), you need to have the data sorted on both branches of the flow and check the `Sorted Input` property on the `Joiner Transformation` (jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason in this case).

A self-join is only allowed if both flows are sorted. Depending on your flow, it may be enough to sort data only once, before the flow gets split.

Now, if you enable the `Sorted Input` property but the data will not be sorted, you will get an error while session execution.

Comment: I tried to add the sort but am still getting the same error.  Am I using the Sorter correctly?  Please see the pictures in my original post. I am sorting by the OR_Case_ID

Comment: Did you check the 'sorted input' property on joiner? Actually THAT is the requirement, not the presence of the Sorter.

Comment: I checked the Sorted Input on the jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason like you said.  I cannot add a Condition for the jnr_Normal_jnr_Master_ZC_OR_Delay_Reason

Comment: It's needed at your target joiner, where you're trying to drag your ports to. The jnr_str_jnr_master_... on the screen.